# Facebook app not working on a page

Tags: facebook

I have a page. I have added two apps on this page.
1) http://www.facebook.com/createtimelinecover?sk=app_171436709583282 and
2) http://www.facebook.com/createtimelinecover?sk=app_170572779643967

First app works perfectly but second one generates an error:-
    "App Temporarily Unavailable
    Parse errors:

```
FBML Error (line 107): illegal tag "body" under "fb:tab-position"

CSS Error (line 250 char 15): Expected identifier for pseudo-class or pseudo-element.      Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.

Runtime errors:

Cannot allow external script"
```

It says illegal tag "body" but when i remove body it works but not working completely. Images doesnt load. I am confused here App 1 works with a tag body but App 2 is not working. Please help.

Comment: Can I suggest you post a link to the page you are referring to (i.e. the page you are trying to debug)?

Comment: Can you post ten or twenty lines that reproduce your problem exactly?

Comment: This http://apps.facebook.com/coloredtetris/ is the app page that i used for page tab http://www.facebook.com/createtimelinecover?sk=app_170572779643967

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not specify http://apps.facebook.com/{appname} as the page tab URL for your page tab app.  To include that app, you need to run this in your browser bar:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID
&display=popup&next=YOUR_PAGE_URL`

Comment: I am again getting the same error. However other apps are running fine.